# Trouble setting Python version in Sublime Text2

Tags: python, macports, sublimetext2

I'm having trouble setting the build environment in Sublime Text2.
I'm using Macports for Python and package installation.

My python.sublime-build file looks like this:

```
{
    "cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

I think (from searching) that I need to modify the "cmd" line to point to the Macports version. Anyone done this successfully?

From Terminal, everything builds/runs fine, it's only Sublime Text2's build that's grabbing the system version still.

Additional info:

```
which python
/opt/local/bin/python
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why not change `python` to `/opt/local/bin/python`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your Sublime Text 2 environment is different from your shell environment; the `$PATH` variable is probably not pointing to the same directories and the wrong executable is selected.

You have several options to work around that:

1. Set a `"path"` option that includes `/opt/local/bin`  need to use an absolute path for your `python` executable, as Sublime Text 2 doesn't share the same environment PATH variable your shell uses. Inspect `echo $PATH` and use that as a template:

   ```
   {
       "cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file"],
       "path": "/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/Users/yourloginname/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin",
       "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
       "selector": "source.python"
   }
   ```

   That'll use `/bin/bash` to run the command, which I think would have the same `$PATH` setting as your terminal.
2. Run the command through the shell instead by setting the `"shell"` option:

   ```
   {
       "cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file"],
       "shell": true,
       "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
       "selector": "source.python"
   }
   ```
3. Use the full path for the python command:

   ```
   {
       "cmd": ["/opt/local/bin/python", "-u", "$file"],
       "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
       "selector": "source.python"
   }
   ```

Comment: The Example 2 will not output print messages or any other messsage to the sublime console.