# Where is the configuration files for sublimeText 2.0.1 on Ubuntu 64 bit 12.04?

Tags: settings, sublimetext2

I'm trying to change my python version to be /usr/bin/python3 which I would make the change, according to default settings:

```
// Settings may also be placed in file type specific options files, for
// example, in Packages/Python/Python.sublime-settings for python files.
```

I simply cannot find the Packages/Python/ or Python.sublime-settings directory or file.
[Trouble setting Python version in Sublime Text2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12342004/trouble-setting-python-version-in-sublime-text2)

I verified a fresh download also lacks this folder structure.  Where is the directory and/or file(s) for user defined settings for the Ubuntu 64 bit package?

Comment: Just located it in my Portable Win 64 bit directories.  Its found relative to the root, /SublimeText2.0x64/Data/Packages/Python/

Comment: You can access this folder through Sublime Text Preferences menu.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`Packages/Python/` directory should be located in

```
~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Python
```

A tip to find where `Packages` directory is located: open the Default Settings, from menu `Preferences/Settings-Default` and look at the full path of the file:

[image]

Comment: Good sleuthing on that one!  I didn't think to look at the path of the default preferences to see where it resides.  Thanks!