# Two Pythons: cannot import from within Sublime, works in Terminal

Tags: python, macos, sublimetext2

I don't know why after a year this suddenly became an issue, but I pip-installed requests and I got an import error when running from Sublime, but it worked fine in the terminal.

I dug a little and found that the terminal was running Python 2.7.3 from `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python` (where requests worked) and Sublime was using 2.7.2 from `/usr/bin/python`.  That's where my know-how ends, and this is an area I'm reluctant to fiddle with if I don't know what I'm doing.  I'm using OSX 10.8.2.  Any suggestions?  Not even sure what to Google.

Comment: I suggest that you start to use [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/)

Comment: You should check which python pip was installed with.  An easy way to check is to type "vi \`which pip\`". and look at the path after the `#!` character.  It might be pointing to the wrong python, and therefore your extensions might be installed in the wrong place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using a newer, non-system Python (which is a good idea), you need to tell Sublime Text 2 to use that Python.  Although your shell `$PATH` was modified to include the location of the newer Python, Sublime Text doesn't know about that.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12342473/145403) for various ways to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to start using [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/) and [virtualenvwrapper](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/) when developing. It gives you a sandboxed python environment for each of your projects.

Comment: `virutalenv` is fine but won't help with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was led to this question/answer (by the above Ned Deily, no less) that solved everything.  Hope it helps someone else!  (Ned, would love to give you the karma, but at 26.7k it doesn't look like you're in dire need).

[How to uninstall Python 2.7 on a Mac OS X 10.6.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4)

Comment: Reverting to using the older Apple-supplied system Python is a fairly drastic solution.  There really shouldn't be a need to do that if you follow one of the suggested changes to Sublime Text 2 (I hope I was correct in assuming that you are using ST2).  But if you feel more comfortable going this way and it works for you, great!