# Get Sublime 3 + Python 3 work together on OS X

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, sublimetext3

I am not only a total newcomer to Sublime text, but also to coding in general, so sorry if I am just to stupid to find an answer...

I am working through my first python tutorial and want to start learning it with python 3. I also want to do that with Sublime Text 3 on OS X (I am also new to that). I found out that Sublime Text 3 works with Python 3, but, not on my system (Build 3047):

```
import sys
print (sys.version)
```

2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)]
[Finished in 0.0s]

How can I get ST to work with Python 3?? I am searching the web for hours and found some people with the same problem but no answer (at least not on OS X).

Answer (score 1):

Download and install Python 3 from the [Python releases page](http://www.python.org/download/releases/); Mac OS X installers are available.

Sublime Text 3 uses Python 3 internally, but that is an embedded Python not suitable for installing your own packages into.

You ran the default system Python, on OS X 10.8 that is still version 2.7. If you have installed Python 3, make sure you start it with `python3`.

Comment: I'm not sure that using the python.org binary release installers is a good idea anymore. At least with Xcode 5.0.1 and OS X 10.8.5 and 10.9.0, it's very hard to build C extension modules against those installations. And I'm not sure how python.org is going to fix that, but I'm guessing it's going to take a while. While I'm waiting, I've been using a Homebrew Python 3 instead. (And if you need to use `py2app` or similar to distribute standalone python binaries, you need to keep an old machine around with OS X 10.8.x and Xcode 4.x.)

Comment: @abarnert: Personally, I use the https://github.com/collective/buildout.python setup; I didn't think that advising what appears to be a beginner to go out and install more command-line tools like Homebrew, though. I was not aware that XCode and the current Python.org builds would conflict, that *is* a pity.

Comment: I did the install and started Idle and it works. But, with ST3 still not. Now if I do the sys.version check I get: 
/usr/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in ''
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u ""]
[dir: /Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]

Comment: Did you set the [python version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12342004/trouble-setting-python-version-in-sublime-text2/12342473#12342473) yet?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thx for your help. I understand that I have to modify the python.sublime-build, right? But where can I find that config. file? If i "browse packages", apart from cache, all folders are empty. (In the terminal I can change between Python2+3 without a problem)

Comment: You create a new file; see http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/sublime-text-3/file_processing/build_systems.html#where-to-store-build-systems for the location.

Comment: thx for the help but I give up, I created the files did it like in your link but nothing. I followed about a dozen tutorials for hours without success, I just can't find a concise beginner tutorial. It seems every case is a special case. I also tried it with pycharm and played around
/usr/local/bin/python3.3 /Users/berndklamper/Downloads/Code/123.py
3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 13 2013, 13:52:24) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]

Process finished with exit code 0

I probably messed my system already up, I can't even remember what I all did. So frustrating...

Comment: As a late followup, I don't understand @abarnert's comment: "I'm not sure that using the python.org binary release installers is a good idea anymore. At least with Xcode 5.0.1 and OS X 10.8.5 and 10.9.0, it's very hard to build C extension modules against those installations. And I'm not sure how python.org is going to fix that, but I'm guessing it's going to take a while."  There shouldn't be any problems if you properly install the current Xcode Command Line Tools for the version of OS X in use, e.g. for 10.9+ including: 'xcode-select --install`.